# listbox; number of selected items

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

While using listbox in c#, how can learn the count of selecteditems?

Listbox items: A,B,C,D. For example, I select C and D.

I want to make a loop in order to assign selecteditems.

How can I achieve it? How can I learn the number of selected item?

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this [`listbox1.GetSelectedIndices().Count();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.getselectedindices.aspx)

Comment: +1 I don't think it is necessary to add a loop if count is all that is needed.

Comment: thank you V4Vendetta, the solution which I look for, is yours.

Comment: .SelectedItems.Count

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code:

This return integer:

```
 listBox.SelectedItems.Count
```

this will return the number as string :

```
listBox.SelectedItems.Count.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You ought to be able to achieve this using something like so:

```
var count = (from item in listBox.Items where item.Selected select item).Count();
```

The above is a way to get this using Linq (so you will need a reference to `System.Linq`) but could easily be expanded to use a more primitive means such as a loop.

Comment: it draws red under the listbox in my code, also I change the name of Listbox according to my code...
And I reference System.Linq;

Comment: @csharper: `listBox` should be replaced by the `ID` of your own `ListBox` control.

Comment: Have you added `using System.Linq;` at the top of your .cs file?

Comment: Yes I add it at the top of file?

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;
foreach(ListItem item in this.ListBox1.Items)
{
  if(item.Selected)
  {
     count++;
   }
}
int c = count;
```