# c# count selected options in listbox

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

I'm having some issues with counting the selected options in a listbox.

I'm using the following code as per the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160459/listbox-number-of-selected-items).

```
myListBox.GetSelectedIndices().Count();
```

I've included the `System.Web` resource and added `using System.Web.UI.WebControls;`  to the top of my code, however, I'm receiving the following error message and I'm stumped on how to fix it.

> 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetSelectedIndices' and no extension method 'GetSelectedIndices'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

The project utilizes .NET 4.0 as the target framework.

Comment: Are you using WinForms or ASP.NET?

Comment: The question you took the code from is for ASP.NET, for WinForms, use `myListBox.SelectedItems.Count`.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, but I received this error now: `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`

Comment: Try this: `int myCount = myListBox.SelectedItems.Count;`

Answer (score 2):

`myListBox.SelectedItems.Count;`

Answer (score 0):

Try `.SelectedItems`, should work on winform

It's not exactly the same ListBox in WinForms and ASP.Net